Power Automate - email inputs
I have a PowerApp and the screen requires a user to input a text (textinput8) and then choose a state from the drop down list (dropdown1). Once the user fills in both the text input and the drop down they can hit the submit button to the next screen. How can I create a power automate so that when the users hit submit it emails the inputs to them?
Thanks! :)

You can create a flow within your app or add already existing flow doing the same task of sending email.
Step1. Create New Flow

Step 2: Have two input values and send Email, I used Gmail.

Step 3: On submit Button run the flow.


See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/button-user-input/3-email-photo

Just a add on, in case if you don't want to use power-automate flow, then you send from direct PowerApp as well. Follow the following steps:

Add connector form the left pane data tab
Add following code on your Submit button.

Office365Outlook.SendEmailV2( 
  User().Email, // Automatically fetch email of current logged in user
  "Sample Subject",
  "Sample Body", // You can use HTML formatted text here, and push your all data which you want to share with user
  {Attachments: Blank()}
)

